# My post operation is not working

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on a project that involves registering users into a mongodatabase.

I have my Mongoose Schema in a file called user.js, here is the code in it:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let UserSchema = Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },

  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  profilePic: {
    type: String
  },

  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },

  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  usersRecipes: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Recipe'}],

  userComments: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Recipe'}]

});

let User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And I here is the code for my file userRouter.js where my code is not working

```
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('Here are the users!')
});

router.get('/:username', (req, res, next) => {
    let nameQuery = {username: req.params.username};

    User.findOne(nameQuery, (err, user) =>{
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(user);

    })
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next, err){

    User.create({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        profilePic: req.body.profilePic
    }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) return err;

        res.json(user);
    }); 
});
module.exports = router;
```

Everytime I try to add a user in postman, I get this error:
[image]

Here is my app.js file:

```
let express = require('express');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let path = require('path');
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let recipeRouter = require('./routes/recipeRouter');
let userRouter = require('./routes/userRouter');
let bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
let passport = require('passport');
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
let config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost:27017);

let db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {
    // we're connected!
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
});

const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.listen(port);


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/recipes',recipeRouter);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hey, this is your database!')
});


module.exports = app;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how have you attached `router` to your `app` ?

Comment: I just added the code to my app.js file. I do attach the userRouter using app.use() but its not working

Comment: Are you exporting your user router before you import it?

Comment: in userRouter, it's written as module.exports = router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next, err) { ... })
```

Specifically, that fourth `err` argument. Passing a function that takes 4 arguments has an internal significance for Express, meaning that the function is an error handler, which it isn't in this case.

Use this instead:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) { ... })
```

Also, a bit later on in your code:

```
if (err) return err;
```

You probably want to throw that error (or call `return next(err)`).

Comment: do I put return next(err) within the register function? Or should I also put it in the other ones also?

Comment: `if (err) return next(err)` (or `if (err) throw err`, whichever you prefer, just not `if (err) return err` because Express ignores return values from route handlers).